# Can we make the link formatting more obvious in the suggested edits queue?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, hyperlinks, markdown

Link in a suggested edit show up as such:

[image]

You can't even tell that it is a link. It isn't obvious until you mouseover the text and even then, you can miss it really easily:

[image]
I've rejected a couple edits because it wasn't apparent that the user had added a link. Can we make this more obvious in the queue? Maybe make the text blue and add a highlight? Like this:

[image]

Comment: On one hand this might indeed help but on the other hand it's up to the one suggesting to make it clear what he/she have done e.g. "added a link" then you can look more closely in the changes.

Comment: Whenever I come across edits like that that where the change is not immediately clear to me, I check the markdown diff too. There are two options for comparing changes for a reason. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh. I didn't think about that, but thanks for pointing it out.